# Vertical Center in Tabularx

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I know this question has asked many times before, but is there maybe another efficient way to really vertically centre text in a tabularx environment?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=1.4cm,footskip=0cm,headheight=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{table_lines}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.24} % define color
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % page numbering
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove top line
\usepackage{colortbl} % column lines color
\usepackage{tabularx} % different column width
  \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\thickhline}{\noalign {\hrule height 2pt}}
    \newcolumntype{'}{!{\color{table_lines}\vrule}}
  \makeatother
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % fancy section
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{} % remove footnote line
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
  \def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
  \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}} % vertical center in tabualrx
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{' L{0.20} '@{}L{0.53} ' C{0.27} '}
    \arrayrulecolor{table_lines}\hline
    0 & 11/02/2011 & \raisebox{-0.05cm}{1} \\[0.0775cm]\hline
    Hallelujah & 04/17/2012 & \raisebox{-0.05cm}{1} \\[0.0775cm]\hline
    1 & 07/05/2013 & \raisebox{-0.05cm}{0} \\[0.0775cm]\arrayrulecolor{table_lines}\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.7cm}
\end{document}
```

The results is as in the picture and you can see that the text is not really centred.
[image]

Comment: The entries are only one line, so vertical centre is almost indistinguishable from top or bottom alignment if you apply it to all the columns. Did you mean _horizontal_ alignment????

Comment: yea, it may be hard to see but they are not really vertically centred, but this is what I am actually looking for. Maybe it isn't so easily doable, but that is what I want to find out.

Comment: @Hiro They are vertically centered. See slashes.

Comment: @Hiro the vertical centres of each entry are lined up, but as the entries in each column are single row they are all aligned just as if they had baseline alignment. For such a table anything other than baseline alignment is going to look really odd anyway!

Comment: @Hiro it isn't clear what you are looking for but `m` does not change the position of the entries between the horizontal lines (if that is what you are looking at) it specifies the alignment between different entries in the same row, that they should all align on their vertical centres not their baselines, but in a situation where the entries have the same height then there is no visual difference between baseline and centre  alignment.

Comment: The non-vertical centring comes mainly from your `[0.0775cm]` at the end of the rows.

Comment: @buhtz why did you ping me It wasn't my example:-)

Comment: @Hiro Your code is not really a minimal working example. Please reedit and remove unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the alignment was off due to the `\raisebox` and extra length specified to `\\[.]` however you also want to add a little extra space above each row to compensate for the visual effect of the descender on `/` making the digits appear over-high within their row.

Something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=1.4cm,footskip=0cm,headheight=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{table_lines}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.24} % define color


\usepackage{colortbl} % column lines color
\usepackage{tabularx} % different column width
  \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\thickhline}{\noalign {\hrule height 2pt}}
    \newcolumntype{'}{!{\color{table_lines}\vrule}}
  \makeatother




\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
  \addtolength\extrarowheight{1.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{' L{0.20} '@{}L{0.53} ' C{0.27} '}
    \arrayrulecolor{table_lines}\hline
    0 & 11/02/2011 & 1 \\\hline
    Hallelujah & 04/17/2012 & 1 \\\hline
    1 & 07/05/2013 & 0 \\\arrayrulecolor{table_lines}\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.7cm}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally as there is no line breaking within the rows `tabularx` isn't doing very much useful work here, I'd simply use `tabular` (although the vertical spacing is the same)