# How to correctly vertical-center cells in a tabularx?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I want to add additional spacing to table rows/cells for a `tabularx`. However, after setting `\arraystretch` to something larger than 1 and setting `\tabularxcolumn` to `m` (see below), I notice that the content is somewhat vertically centered but shifted considerably down, i.e. below the vertical center of each cell.

**How I correctly center this?**

[image: example rendered]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
hello & world \\
\hline
hello & x\vspace{20ex}\newline world \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I've found [some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122266/1498) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343574/1498) that hack some seemingly random spacing to the top. However, this doesn't appear to address this particular issue. At least I don't see a general solution by adding a fixed space of e.g. `{-1ex}` as the spacing appears to depend on the content size. If my eyes play tricks on me and the offset is indeed constant, **how do I determine the *exact* offset?**

---

**Edit: `cellspace` does *NOT* appear to work in my context. These are the troubles with a minimal working example, I guess.**

Comment: Could you please post a minimal example reproducing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, combining the redefinition of the `X` column type as an `m{...}` column, and the `S` pre-column specifier of `cellspace`, which ensures a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns so prefixed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, cellspace}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{30pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{30pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|S{X}|S{X}|}
\hline
hello & world \\
\hline
hello & x \newline world \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the `cellspace` package you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2.5\baselineskip}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|SX|SX|}
\hline
hello & world \\
\hline
hello & x\vspace{20ex}\newline world  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's better to also redefine the `X` column type. See the layout if you remove \vpace{20ex}.

Answer (score 0):

You can direct a `\vspace{fill}` before and after the cell's content, using `>{}` syntax. If you only have this type of X columns, you put the redirection into the redefinition of the X column, *i.e.*:

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\vspace{\fill}}m{#1}<{\vspace{\fill}}}
```

You may also use `p`-columns and a standard tabular. To have the content exactly centred, you need to terminate the cells with `\par`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, array}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\vspace{\fill}}m{#1}<{\vspace{\fill}}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{5}

\newcolumntype{P}{m{\dimexpr(0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth)}}

\begin{document}

%% tabularx and redefined `X`-columns

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
hello\par& world\par\\
\hline
hello\par & x\vspace{20ex}\newline world\par\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{2cm}

%% Tabular and `m`-columns

\begin{tabular}{|P|P|}
\hline
hello\par& world\par\\
\hline
hello\par& x\vspace{20ex}\newline world\par\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```